# PostgreSQL v9.X have real "array of record"?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, record

This query works fine,

```
 WITH test AS (
   SELECT array_agg(t) as x FROM (
     SELECT 1111 as id, 'aaaaa' as cc  
   ) AS t
 ) SELECT x[1] FROM test;
```

but,  **can I access the recod elements?**  I try `SELECT x[1].id`;  `SELECT x[1][1]`; ... nothing works.

PS: with Google we see only OLD solutions... The context here is v9.X, no news about "array of record"?

---

I try also

```
 select x[1] from (select array[row(1,2)] as x) as t;
```

no solution to access only item 1 or only item 2.

---

A clue that I was unable to follow: [postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Arrays-of-records-td1884523.html) solve the problem using a `CREATE TYPE`... Ok, but I need "all in a query" solution. Where the "dynamic typing" of PostgreSQL??  How to CAST or express the type without a `CREATE TYPE` clause?

Comment: You can convert the value to `hstore` and grab fields out of it that way, but that's not really what you want. PostgreSQL's `record` pseudo-type is a bit limited - in particular, there's no anonymous record cast, e.g. `CAST(somerecord AS t(x integer, y text))` doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, if this is something you want, you'll need to make noise about it, and probably back that noise with the willingness to do real work and/or contribute toward dev time. It's a bit of a corner of the type system, and nobody's really keen on working on it, so you need to care enough to make it happen yourself, or find ways to make others care enough to deal with it.

Comment: Do you have more context for this? There might be another way to get where you need to be.

Comment: Sorry @Mu, we not need "more context", is a syntatic contradiction of PostgreSQL... I think Craig confirms my deception with pg9.X: no news.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger, you understand my deceptions, and show a better name: **"anonymous record cast"** is the "syntax lack" of PG. That was what I looking for, when building this kind of queries. PostgreSQL allows expressing "something that seems Array of Recortd" but disappoint us at the half way...  Yes, I need to make noise about many little things, but perhaps the first noise is *"Hello PG-Community! We are at 2014! Where the RFC site? Where the interface for [Stakeholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder_%28corporate%29) to vote!??"*

Comment: @PeterKrauss It's open source. Your're a stakeholder if you contribute - be that helping people on the lists or here, detailed design, bug hunting and reporting, bug fixing, code cleanups, feature contributions, patch review, etc etc. I suggest getting involved and contributing if you want to be heard. (Also, please don't say "9.x" - 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, ... are all major releases. Yes, that's stupid, but we're stuck with it). You care about this thing - others care about bidirectional replication, others about row-level security and multi-tenant, ... . Make noise, be heard, contribute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At present there does not appear to be any syntax for accessing a record of anonymous type except via the function call syntax or via hstore. That's unfortunate, but not likely to get fixed in a hurry unless someone who really cares comes along to make it happen. There are other priorities.

You have three workaround options:

- `CREATE TYPE`
- `hstore`

### `CREATE TYPE`

The issue is with records of anonymous type. So make it not anonymous. Unfortunately this is only possible before it becomes an anonymous record type; you can't currently cast from `record` to a usertype. So you'd need to do:

```
CREATE TYPE some_t AS (id integer, cc text);

WITH test AS (
   SELECT array_agg(t::some_t) as x FROM (
     SELECT 1111 as id, 'aaaaa' as cc  
   ) AS t
 ) SELECT x[1].id FROM test;
```

Note the cast of the subquery output to `some_t` before aggregation.

I can't say I understand why this cast can't be performed after indexing the array instead.

### `hstore`

As usual, `hstore` rides to the mostly-rescue with difficult type problems.

```
regress=> WITH test AS (
       SELECT array_agg(t) as x FROM (
         SELECT 1111 as id,  'aaaaa' as cc  
       ) AS t
     ) SELECT hstore(x[1])->'id' FROM test;
 ?column? 
----------
 1111
(1 row)
```

You need the `hstore` extension, and I'm sure it's not efficient, but it works. This builds on the `hstore` support for creating a hstore from anonymous records that was added to support `NEW` and `OLD` in triggers, a past pain-point.

### Wrapper function?

Turns out you can't get around it with a simple wrapper function to let you specify the type on the call-site:

```
regress=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION identity(record) RETURNS record AS $$
          SELECT $1; 
          $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
ERROR:  SQL functions cannot have arguments of type record
```

so you'd have to use a higher-overhead procedural language, at which point you might as well use hstore instead, it'll be faster and easier.

### Making it better?

So, this is all a bit ugly. It's not ever likely to be possible to directly index a field from an anonymous record, since it might not exist and its type cannot be deduced. But there's no reason we can't use the type system feature that allows us to return `record` from a function and specify its type on the caller-side to also do so in casts.

It should be possible to make PostgreSQL support something like:

```
WITH test AS (
   SELECT array_agg(t) as x FROM (
      SELECT 1111 as id,  'aaaaa' as cc  
   ) AS t
) SELECT (x[1] AS some_t(id integer, cc text)).id  FROM test;
```

it'd just involve appropriate parser-hacking, and a way to make sure that was never ambiguously parsed in conflict with a column-alias.

Really, even type-inference could be possible if someone was willing to put the work in and convince the team that the rather large amount of query-planner processor time required was worth it. (unlikely).

This is an irritating, but minor, corner in the type system. If you want it to change you will need to make noise on pgsql-general, and accompany that noise with the willingness to do real work to improve the problem. This may involve learning more than you ever wanted to know about the innards of PostgreSQL's type system, learning the fun of "backward compatibility", and having frustrating arguments around and around in circles. Welcome to open source!