# Functions can not to return individual items of a record, is it? Any workaround?

Tags: function, postgresql, data-access

Basic things as [*struct* in C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Structures), exist in all popular languages, and is expected that functions, of these languages, also can return a *struct*... And, by an  orthogonality principle, is expected you can access the returned *struct itens*.

PostgreSQL, nevertheless, did not offer access to the *struct itens* of a `FUNCTION ... RETURNS RECORD`. It is correct?

But programmers use PostgreSQL without complaining...  **There are a simple and intuitive workaround?**

---

Similar question: [PostgreSQL v9.X have real "array of record"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21246201/287948)

---

### Illustrating by typical cases

```sql
 CREATE FUNCTION foo(int) RETURNS RECORD AS $$ 
      SELECT $1 as a, 'Hello #'||$1 as b; 
 $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

 SELECT foo(6);       -- works, but I need only one item
```

Access of record itens in a **SQL context**:

```
 SELECT (foo(6)).a;   -- NOT works (but no ambiguity!)

 -- For syntax discussion:
 WITH f AS (SELECT foo(6) as r) SELECT r.a FROM f; -- NOT works
 -- ambiguous syntax; confused r with table, in "f.r.a", f with schema 
 -- perhaps r['a'] would be a good syntax solution
```

Access of record itens in a **PLpgSQL context**:

How to say `x:=(foo(6)).a` or `y:=foo(6); x:=y.a`? Now there are some expected behaviuor, in PLpgSQL, at least "named record" is permitted:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION bar() RETURNS text AS $F$ 
DECLARE 
   tmp record;
   s text;
BEGIN 
   -- s:=(foo(7)).b;  NOT WORKS, is like an "anonymous record" (not permitted)
   tmp := foo(6); 
   s:=tmp.b;  -- IT WORKS!! is like a "named record" (permitted)
   RETURN s||'! '||tmp.a;  --  ...works accessing any other individual itens
END;
$F$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: `SQL` is not `C` - what is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If your assertion about "no performance overhead" is ok, the real problem is my ignorance about the "(complex) PostgreSQL way" to do the simple things. I accepted your solution because you show all possibilities... **good answer**!. My comments at your answer, by other hand (sorry confusion), changed the focus. If a  benckmark demonstrates performance differences,  my comments are only a little "protest over this lack of the PostgreSQL-language": performance will be more one rationale/justification to the need of *anonymous record*, as [showed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258289/287948).

Comment: My question is: why do (think) you need an "anonymous record"?

Comment: Because (summarizing my other comments) to create a new data type for *each function return* is a big overhead and "type space pollution"... Even with no ambiguity, `SELECT (foo(6)).a` today (pg 9.3) is not permitted, because "anonymous record" is not permitted... See also the *[array of records](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21246201/287948)* problem, where the "anonymous record" would be a solution.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are *really* trying to achieve. SQL doesn't work with "single records", it works with sets of rows. I have a suspicion that you are tackling your real (business) problem from the wrong angle. And if you give up "thinking in C" you might arrive at a much better solution but as you fail to disclose the real problem there is nothing we can do to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the more flexible `returns table` instead of (the somewhat outdated) `returns record`, then things get really easy:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(int) RETURNS table (a int, b text) 
AS 
$$ 
  SELECT $1 as a, 'Hello #'||$1 as b; 
$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

now you can use:

```
select b
from foo(6);
```

If you are concerned about "tables" vs. "records" you can also define a `type` to overcome the additional result set definition:

```
create type foo_return as (a int, b text);
CREATE FUNCTION foo(int) RETURNS foo_return
AS 
$$ 
  SELECT $1, 'Hello #'||$1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

You can still the above select then:

```
select b
from foo(6);
```

A third maybe more "C" like approach would be to use out parameters ([as shown in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html))

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(p1 int, out a int, out b text)
AS
$$ 
  SELECT $1, 'Hello #'||$1;
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then you don't need a `from` :

```
select (foo(1)).b;
```

Comment: Yes, good syntax workaround (!). Well, I think that Clodoaldo's solution have better performance -- do you think it? I'm imagining the tables as elephants compared to the records. So there are no 100% solution: I need to choose between "good syntax" and "good performance".

Comment: @PeterKrauss: to be honest: I wouldn't expect any difference in performance, but if you really can't free yourself of thinking in "records" then you might want to use a defined `type`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! yes, you show the "(complex) PostgreSQL way" to do the simple things. I was looking for access record itens by somthing as `(foo(6)).a` or `(foo(6))['a']`... My question is perhaps silly, but, anyway, stay as a protest over this lack of the PostgreSQL-language... by my point of view, it need "more direct/elegant syntactic solution" and  "less type-space pollution".

Comment: @PeterKrauss: see my edt. There is a way to use `(foo(6)).a` - but this all sounds to me as if you are focusing on a technical solution that might not be the correct way to solve the actual problem you have. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: You answered my question, the real problem is only "how to" and "not loss performance". (ops, and now you edited showing also how to access without FROM clause, thanks also).  My comments here changed the focus (sorry the confusion), back to [Craig's explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258289/287948) , about the lack of "anonymous record" in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Is this simple and intuitive?

```
select a 
from foo(6) s(a int, b text);
```

Comment: It works (!), what is a good starting point... But, as @ErwinBrandstetter [commented here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11911949/287948), "(...) this is *very unwieldy* as you have to provide the column definition list with every call".  There are a way to express (a int, b text) in the function creation?